# Changing the default user groups when creating a project

Tags: jira

When a project is created in Jira, the jira-users group is added by default, which gives all users access to the project (which we don't want).  I know that this can be changed manually after the project is created, but is it possible to configure Jira so that another group is used by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe to do this you go to the Administration Screen -> Project Role Browser and remove jira-users from the Default Members for the Users Role.